# Spotify API Authorization to create a Playlist

Tags: python, api, authorization, spotify, spotipy

I've been trying to write a code with the Spotify for Developers Tools that will read the audio features of all the songs in a user selected playlist and then create two new playlists to sort the songs in the original playlist depending on whether they are considered minor or major. I have gotten most of the program to work, it reads the playlist and creates a dictionary of the songs audio features and creates two lists for the songs that are minor and one for the major, however it will not let me create a new playlist due to the authorization and I can not figure out how to solve this issue. Below is my code, any help is greatly appreciated!

Here is what the beginning looks like with my account information:

```
################### Account Information ######################

cid ='*my client id*' # Client ID
secret = '*my secret id*' # Client Secret
client_credentials_manager = SpotifyClientCredentials(client_id=cid, client_secret=secret)
sp = spotipy.Spotify(client_credentials_manager=client_credentials_manager)
username = '*my username*' 
token = util.prompt_for_user_token(username=username, scope='playlist-modify-public', client_id=cid, client_secret=secret, redirect_uri="http://localhost:8888/callback")

#############################################################
```

Then I try to create the playlists:

```
############### Create Playlist #################

created_playlist_minor = sp.user_playlist_create(username, "New Playlist Minor", description='Minor')
created_playlist_major = sp.user_playlist_create(username, "New Playlist Major", description='Major')
created_playlist_other = sp.user_playlist_create(username, "New Playlist Other", description='Other')

#################################################
```

And then it gives me an error

```
spotipy.client.SpotifyException: http status: 403, code:-1 - https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/*username*/playlists:
This request requires user authentication.
```

Comment: Did you pass any scopes? Like, scope = 'user-follow-modify playlist-modify-private'

Answer (score 0):

You are passing in a `SpotifyClientCredentials` object to your `Spotify` client. This authenticates `spotipy.Spotify` so that you can do anything that your developer API key gives you access to (e.g. getting info about songs in a public playlist). You haven't given your `spotipy.Spotify` a user's authentication token, so you can't do user-specific things like creating a playlist. You should do the following:

```
username = '*my username*' 
token = util.prompt_for_user_token(
    username=username,
    scope='playlist-modify-public', 
    client_id=cid, 
    client_secret=secret, 
    redirect_uri="http://localhost:8888/callback"
)
sp = spotipy.Spotify(auth=token)
```

Note that you don't have to pass your Client ID & Secret to `spotipy.Spotify`, the token is sufficient